# how to delete individual objects placed with the scatter objects addon?

Tags: add-on, scatter-objects-addon

i used the scatter objects addon (it comes with blender) to scatter city buildings and there is this 1 building thats just so out of place and i want it gone but all the scattered objects are the same object and also clones of the original so they technically dont have any geometry

[here is the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DUE0uq3Hw2v_KSwqevHipzwlJoPedyYK/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This addon creates a new object made of a series of triangle meshes on the surface of the target object, and this new object has its *Instancing > Faces* enabled so that it creates a duplication of the desired object on each triangle. To remove some of the instances, select the object, switch to *Edit* mode and remove the triangles you want.

[image]